# String split differences in two pairs of columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains strings in this format and more. This is how the table looks like, NOTE that this is just a small subset of the data, I have more than 16 columns:

```
x <- data.frame("v1_old" = c("[is_minimum] = '0'", "[is_minimum] = '0'"),
                "v1_new" = c("[is_minimum] = '0' and [is_minimum] = '1'", "[is_minimum] = '0' and [t_sheet] ='1'"))
```

Now I am comparing two pair of columns each pair having suffix _old and _new respectively and spotting differences within the strings of each row then be able to create a new column with suffix **_diff** meaning differences.

Now I have tried with this first code
**CODE1:**

```
df <- data.frame(x)
old_cols <- grep("old$", names(df), value = TRUE)
new_cols <- grep("new$", names(df), value = TRUE)

df[sub("new$", "diff", new_cols)] <- Map(stringr::str_remove, 
                                         df[new_cols], df[old_cols])
```

and this is the result I get with this code
**RESULT1**

```
result <- data.frame("v1_old" = c("[is_minimum] = '0'", "[is_minimum] = '0'"),
                "v1_new" = c("[is_minimum] = '0' and [is_minimum] = '1'", "[is_minimum] = '0' and [t_sheet] ='1'"),
                "v1_diff" = c ("[is_minimum] = '0' and [is_minimum] = '1'", "[is_minimum] = '0' and [t_sheet] ='1'"))
```

This is not the result I expect. I want the diff column to only have that part which doesn't exist in previous old column comparison.

Now I have this code which gives me the right result but the problem is I have to keep manually changing column names to get the result. It's not efficient, I expect the same result but automate column selection since I have multiple columns. My question is how can I automate this code to work like the first one and give me the same result. This is the code and result. **NOTE** each two pair of columns have the same name only that they have a suffix _old and _new like this (v1_old,v1_new, age_old,age_new, town_old,town_new..like so and so. I am comparing each pair.
**CODE2**

```
x$v1_diff<- mapply(function(x, y) paste(setdiff(y, x), collapse = '| '), strsplit(x$v1_old, '\\||, | | -| \\+'), strsplit(x$v1_new, '\\||, | | -| \\+'))
```

result for this code is:
**RESULT2**

```
result2 <- data.frame("v1_old" = c("[is_minimum] = '0'", "[is_minimum] = '0'"),
                "v1_new" = c("[is_minimum] = '0' and [is_minimum] = '1'", "[is_minimum] = '0' and [t_sheet] ='1'"),
                "v1_diff" = c (" and| '1'", "and| [t_sheet]| ='1'"))
```

The second result is what I expect but as you see with second code I have to keep changing column names manually but with the first code I don't. How can I automate second code or alter it to look like first code but give same output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second method work for you put it in a function and apply it to multiple columns

```
change_func <- function(a, b) {
   mapply(function(x, y) paste(setdiff(y, x), collapse = '| '), 
       strsplit(a, '\\||, | | -| \\+'), strsplit(b, '\\||, | | -| \\+'))
}

df[sub("new$", "diff", new_cols)] <- Map(change_func, df[old_cols], df[new_cols])
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
old_cols <- grep("old$", names(df), value = TRUE)
new_cols <- grep("new$", names(df), value = TRUE)
```